# FacebookSDK with Continuous Integration - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-server, facebook

I've got a project on Xcode which works with FacebookSDK. As recommanded by [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started?locale=fr_FR#sdk), the SDK is installed on ~/Documents/FacebookSDK, and in my Build Settings, I had this path to the "Framework Search Paths" part. Everything works fine, but I'm trying to use Continuous Integration with Xcode Server, and when I try to integrate my project, it can't find the FacebookSDK (I've got this error message : "Issue: 'FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h' file not found.").

I thought it was because the build is made on the server, so I installed FacebookSDK on "~/Documents/FacebookSDK" on the server, but the issue is still here. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally found the solution.

--> Simply add the path to "Libray Search Path". (something like "$(SRCROOT)/Vendor/FacebookSDK")

I don't understand why we don't need this stuff for build and run but for CI, but it works now.

Comment: did you copied the facebook sdk in /vendor folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow this steps:

- Remove old path from Header Search path
- Make sure your FacebookSDK is in your project folder
- Go to Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
- Click on + than go to app folder & select Facebook SDK
- It will set the actual path of SDK
- After that clean project & make build

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Actually, it works fine for build and run on device or simulator, but the error appears when I integrate my project for Continuous Integration with XCode Server.

Comment: @PierreApo make sure you have Linked FacebookSDK from your apps folder. It must me in your App folder other wise it will not work with continuous integration.

Comment: Yes, before it was on ~/Documents/... but now I moved and linked it into the app folder. It still working for build and run, except for CI...

Answer (score 0):

For those who are working with React Native (React Native FBSDK), put `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../Frameworks/FacebookSDK` in `Framework Search Paths` on `RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj` after moving FB SDK to `ios/Frameworks`. It will work.